# JavaScript: How to remove all the square brackets inside the outer array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var arrayX = [ ["fire", "lightning"], [3, "ice"], [85], ["wind", "earth", 0] ];
```

In the example above, `arrayX` consists of four elements, each of which is also an array. As it stands now, `arrayX.length` equals `4`.

I wonder if it is possible to remove all the four pairs of square brackets inside, leaving only the most outer bracket, so that the computer can now count the total number of all the individual elements in `arrayX`. I mean, like this:

```
var arrayX = ["fire", "lightning", 3, "ice", 85, "wind", "earth", 0];
```

Now, `arrayX.length` returns `8`, and this is the number I want to get. I started to learn programming just several days ago, so I'm not sure how to go about this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Create an array and add all the elements to it, by traversing the original array using [for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) loop, or use `arrayX.join().split(',')` but here all the values are converted to string, but `length` will be 8, as per the question.

Comment: The concept you're after is called "flattening" the array.

Answer (score 8):

There is no need to loop

```
arrayX = [].concat.apply([], arrayX);
```

Comment: it works only if the array is not nested.

Comment: @NinaScholz Works fine for OPs case. I love when people add new requirements that do not matter in the OPs case.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Array.prototype.reduce()`:

```
var flattened = [ ["fire", "lightning"], [3, "ice"], [85], ["wind", "earth", 0] ].reduce(function(a, b) {
  return a.concat(b);
}, []);
```

[docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fan of the concat method myself

```js
function concatArray() {
  var arrayX = [
    ["fire", "lightning"],
    [3, "ice"],
    [85],
    ["wind", "earth", 0]
  ];
  arrayX = [].concat.apply([], arrayX);
  console.log(arrayX.length);
}

concatArray();
```

Comment: Was my answer wrong?

Comment: you seem happy , no one here likes that in my exp, avoid 'fan' , 'excelent', 'super' keywords